# xUnit fails on Jenkins even though js tests succeed

Tags: jenkins, jasmine, xunit, frisby.js

We have a CI pipeline on Jenkins. Under test is a REST api running in a Docker container. It is tested with frisby.js which also uses jasmine.

Test are successful

```
Finished in 0.168 seconds
1 test, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

but xUnit sets the build status to FAILURE:

```
[xUnit] [INFO] - Converting '/path/to/TEST-FrisbyTestMyApiTest.xml' .
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Skipped Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to FAILURE
```

Why is that? How can I get it to be SUCCESS?

The paths are validated and correct. The tests run successful. I'm running the Jenkins xUnit plugin with JUnit pattern. All xUnit thresholds are set to 0.

Comment: Have you tried to use JUnit reporter instead of XUnit ? It's working for me.

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. Thanks! However I'll leave the question open if someone finds a solution.

Comment: You have 4 assertions, could that be your issue? Also what is the build status before you get to `[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to FAILURE` as I believe it will get confused if the build is already marked as failed.

Comment: No, 4 assertions are not the issue. I do not have any more informationen than that provided.